# How do I inherit documentation from super classes in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have a Super class that I've done some extensive documentation on.  There are subclasses that inherit from this super class and I would like to reuse the documentation of the super if possible.  For example with Super class `ClassA`:

```
classdef ClassA
    %CLASSA Super Class for all others classes
    %
    % CLASSA Properties:
    %   Prop1       It's the first property
    %   Prop2       It's the second
    %
    % CLASSA Methods:
    %   Method1     It's a method
    %   Method2     It's another method

    function value = Method1(var)
        % Super implementation of Method1
    end

    % Other method definitions follow
end
```

And a subclass, ClassB:

```
classdef ClassB < ClassA
    %CLASSB Subclass of super class CLASSA
    %
    % CLASSB Properties:
    %   Prop3       It's the first property of subclass
    %   
    % CLASSB Methods:
    %   Method 3    It's the first method of subclass

    function value = Method1(var)
        % Subclass implementation of Method1
    end

    % Other method definitions follow
end
```

If I type `help ClassB` I only get `ClassB`'s help description.  I want to have the Super's help description to also be included.  The output would look something like this:

```
 CLASSB Subclass of super class CLASSA

 CLASSB Properties:
    Prop1       It's the first property
    Prop2       It's the second
    Prop3       It's the first property of subclass

 CLASSB Methods:
    Method1     It's a method
    Method2     It's another method
    Method3     It's the first method of subclass
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this; however, you can include a "see also" that will link automatically to your super class; just put `See also CLASSA.` at the end of your `ClassB` documentation and MATLAB will do the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by [@SamRoberts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16424477/97160), there is a [standard way](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-help-for-classes.html) of documenting properties and methods.

For example:

```
classdef Super
    %Super Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here
    %
    % Super Properties:
    %    One - Description of One
    %    Two - Description of Two
    %
    % Super Methods:
    %    myMethod - Description of myMethod
    %

    properties
        One     % First public property
        Two     % Second public property
    end
    properties (Access=private)
        Three   % Do not show this property
    end

    methods
        function obj = Super
            % Summary of constructor
        end
        function myMethod(obj)
            % Summary of myMethod
            disp(obj)
        end
    end
    methods (Static)
        function myStaticMethod
            % Summary of myStaticMethod
        end
    end

end
```

and

```
classdef Derived < Super
    %Derived Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here
    %
    % See also: Super

    properties
        Forth     % Forth public property
    end

    methods
        function obj = Derived
            % Summary of constructor
        end
        function myOtherMethod(obj)
            % Summary of myMethod
            disp(obj)
        end
    end

end
```

Now on the command line, you could say:

[image: help_super]

You get nicely formatted hyperlinks.

Also note what you get with `doc Derived` (or when you highlight the word and press <kbd>F1</kbd>). This internally calls `help2html` to convert the help into HTML. For example, we could do this ourselves:

```
>> %doc Derived
>> web(['text://' help2html('Derived')], '-noaddressbox', '-new')
```

[image: web]

Note that inherited properties/methods are displayed.

Comment: in fact, I once found this behavior of `doc`/`help2html` undesirable especially when your classes inherit from `handle` class. To turn it off, I had to edit internal MALTAB function: `[toolboxdir('matlab') '/helptools/private/help2xml.m']`: http://pastebin.com/AYMa2p5q

Comment: In case you find this useful - rather than modify an internal function, I typically inherit from my own class `HandleHiddenMethods`. This inherits from `handle`, and consists of a single `methods (Hidden=true)` block. In this are copies of all the methods of `handle`, overloaded to just pass the call straight through to `handle`. So `HandleHiddenMethods` behaves the same as `handle`, but doesn't display its methods in the auto-generated documentation. This works for all methods other than `isvalid`, which is Sealed and can't be overloaded.

Comment: @SamRoberts: clever, thanks for sharing this tip. It is not easy to keep track of these modifications, especially when upgrading MATLAB every new release.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing documentation in the way you describe, I think the only way you can get what you're asking for is to overload `help` to do something customised. For example, your overloaded `help` could call `builtin('help')` on itself, and then `builtin('help')` on its superclass.

However, you're not documenting things in the standard way; typically you would document properties using comments immediately above the property itself, and document methods with comments immediately below the function signature of the method. If you did that, then you'd automatically display the help for all the inherited methods.

Comment: Do you have a link to the conventional way of documentation?  I followed the suggestions [outlined here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-help-for-classes.html).

Comment: See @Amro's better answer.